# No accept function on question

Tags: support, specific-question, bounties

I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844569/ckeditor-class-or-id-for-editor-body), but the "accept" checkmarks are missing in the answers.

Why?

I'm going through the documentation but not finding anything about accepting an answer becoming impossible after a certain amount of time but can't find anything.

Comment: Did you set a bounty on it at some point?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think so, no... Would that make a difference? Would't the one answer have been auto-accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set a bounty on it around December 7th. (You can take a look at your reputation graph and look for a point in time where that question cost you more than 50 reputation).

The reason there was no auto-accept is likely because [no answer met the criteria for an auto accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067), and if there is no eligible answer at the end of the bounty, then an answer can never be accepted.

Comment: Ah I see. I must have overlooked this bounty. Thanks. Is there any other way to get additional points to the answer?

Comment: I think the only way is for more people to upvote it.

Comment: There should be a way to reset the acceptance eligibility.. as it is now, the question is effectively dead. No one likes dead questions! :(